# Ionic Refresher. Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ElementRef: (?)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm using **Ionic** and **Angular 4** in my project and trying to integrate Ionic [Refresher](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/refresher/Refresher/). Need to say, that I'm totally new to Ionic and not very good in Angular.

I have imported all dependencies (as I think), but still getting the error:

> Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ElementRef: (?).

Here are my files.

**balances.component.html:**

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content
      pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown"
      pullingText="Pull to refresh"
      refreshingSpinner="circles"
      refreshingText="Refreshing...">
    </ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>
</ion-content>
<!-- other code -->
```

**balances.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Refresher, Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'pc-balances',
  templateUrl: './balances.component.html',
  styles: [``]
})
export class BalancesComponent implements OnInit {   
  constructor(
    public refresher: Refresher,
    public elementRef: ElementRef,
    public content: Content
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  /* Code for Refresher's example */
  doRefresh(refresher) {
    console.log('Begin async operation', refresher);

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Async operation has ended');
      refresher.complete();
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

**balances.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule }           from '@angular/core';
import { ElementRef }         from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule }        from 'ionic-angular';
import { Refresher, Content } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CommonModule }       from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule }       from '../shared/shared.module';
import { HistoryModule }      from '../history/history.module';
import { BalancesComponent }  from './balances.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    HistoryModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    BalancesComponent
  ],
  providers: [Refresher, Content, ElementRef]
})
export class BalancesModule { }
```

As you can see, I have imported necessary dependencies to module and included them to `providers`. I have no idea why I still getting the error, may be I missed something, any help is welcome!

Comment: Why are you using importing `ElementRef` everywhere anyway? You do not use it anywhere in your code.

Comment: That's true, I think that Ionic Refresher needs it to work, and I'm getting the error

Comment: Errors started occurring after adding the basic example from docs: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/refresher/Refresher/ So I'm just trying to solve them. If to get rid of ElementRef from Providers array, I'm getting another error: `Error: No provider for ElementRef!`

Comment: Which version of ionic are you using?

Comment: @David, "ionic-angular": "^3.5.3", "ionic-native": "^2.9.0"

Comment: So you don't need import or inject `ElementRef` anywhere, there is nothing about it in the docs and I'm using the `Refresher` with the same version of ionic _without_ the need of importing `ElementRef`. Using `ElementRef` is anyway not recommended by the angular team as there are many security concerns, use `Renderer` or `Renderer2` if you need access to DOM elements.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I'll keep trying without `ElementRef`

Comment: @David, I founded solution and it's pretty simple. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[ElementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef)*** is not a service. **You should avoid injecting it into providers array**. 
**constructor** of the component is a best place to inject it which you have already done. 
So simply get rid of ***ElementRef*** from ***Providers array***.

Comment: This way I'm getting another error: `Error: No provider for ElementRef!`

Comment: @yurzui, I don't really know, I can suggest that `balances.component` is the right place to do it. But what I really want is to integrate Ionic Refresher. I just copied an example from docs and now trying to solve errors with hope, that Refresher will work.

Comment: I founded solution and it's pretty simple. Thanks for your help.

Comment: what's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks to @David and @micronyks for their help. The solution is very simple: remove `node_modules` folder and rerun `npm i`, and then rerun ionic project. [Refresher](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/refresher/Refresher/) doesn't require any imports except of `import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';` (if you're using both **Ionic** and **Angular 2/4**, I have imported it in `balances.module.ts`) in your module and HTML structure should look like this:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content
      pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown"
      pullingText="Pull to refresh"
      refreshingSpinner="circles"
      refreshingText="Refreshing...">
    </ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>

  <!-- your HTML -->

</ion-content>
```

Hope that it will help someone else.